# Unity 2D Collisions and movement with Lerp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have the player with a Rigidbody2d and a box collider 2D with continuous collision detection and dynamic body type. The boxes the player must jump on are dynamic until they have fallen when their rigidbody gets destroyed to stop the wobbling, the box also has a collider 2d on it yet still the player can move through it. The player must move with a lerp as it must only move a certain distance. I'm pretty sure this is the problem, however, I don't know how t fix it. I have multiple raycasts which work very well except when the player lands on the box diagonally. Any help would be much appreciated.alt text

Thanks

```
    void update(){
    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0 && moveRight == true && moveRightTimer <= 0)
        {
            moveRightTimer = 0.15f;
            moveX += moveDistance;
            if(gameObject.transform.localScale.x < 0)
            {
                flipPlayer();
            }
        }
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
        {
            MovePlayer();
        }
    //Moves the player
    void MovePlayer()
    { 
        Vector2 PlayerPos = gameObject.transform.position;
        PlayerPos.x = moveX;

    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition(PlayerPos + (Vector2)transform.position * Time.deltaTime);

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When setting your player's position, use either `Rigidbody2D.MovePosition()` or `Rigidbody2D.position` to set the position of your transform, rather than the transform's `position` property directly. `Rigidbody2D.MovePosition()` accounts for the interpolation setting on your rigidbody if that is something you wish to use.

[Rigidbody2D.MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html)

[Rigidbody2D.position](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-position.html)

Example:

```
public Rigidbody2D rigid;
public bool UseMovePosition;

void Awake()
{
    rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (UseMovePosition)
        rigid.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * Time.deltaTime);
    else
        rigid.position = transform.position + transform.forward * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

These will set the position and adhere to any collisions that would occur.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick response and it does fix the colliding problem however when the player moves now it kinda teleports there and is unable to jump. Any more ideas would be awesome thanks! I've edited the post at the top to include my code.

Comment: Ahh, well in that case you're going to have to do a little bit more complicated of a controller that does a few things   (1) Check if the character is grounded and apply gravity if not.
   (2) Only allow jumping when grounded.
   (3) Move the character through the `velocity` property of the rigidbody.
There is an excellent video from unity that walks through creating this very script which can be found [here](https://youtu.be/Xnyb2f6Qqzg?t=37m45s)

Comment: Thanks again however how would I move the character a specific amount with velocity as it didn't seem to explain that in the video? Last time I tried that the player was glitching between positions. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Well the velocity property essentially translates how far in meters the object will move over 1 second. So if you were already calculating the distance the player should move with lerp before, it's pretty similar. Whatever you were using to calculate the interpolant parameter (the 0-1 parameter representing the progress of the lerp), maybe you can translate that into a specific distance over 1 second? I'm also a bit confused as the Rigidbody2D.MovePosition or Rigidbody2d.position would have achieved the specific amount, but you said it was teleporting. How is that different from what you want?

Comment: Hi again. Unfortunately, I am still having this problem and have tried moving with velocity however I am still a little unsure as to how to move a certain amount of velocity. Could you please post some code if that's possible? Thanks and I really appreciate your help.